# Вызвать alert в zabbix отправив HTTP (POST)

Tags: zabbix

Кто знает, есть ли возможность в заббикс отправить уведомление о событии обратившись к нему просто по HTTP?

У нас нету возможности ставить агент, или пинговать или каким-либо другим способом обращаться К тому месту ОТКУДА придёт алерт. Мы только ТОЛЬКО ЛИШЬ, ИЗ этого места обратиться к заббиксу и только HTTP?

Это возможно в заббиксе?

Например чтобы алерт произошел при обращении типа:

```
http://zabbix-server.com/query?id=12345
```

Answer (score 2):

Два варианта:

**1. Эмуляция zabbix протокола**

Вы можете эмулировать со своей стороны [Zabbix Protocol](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/ru/manual/appendix/items/activepassive?s[]=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)

Шлите пакеты на порт Zabbix server'а с требуемыми item'мами

**2. PHP-скрипт со стороны Zabbix Server**

Закинуть в zabbix server скрипт на php с собственной имплементацией дальнейших действий

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш веб сервер ведет логи ,то можете просто парсить логи сервера на наличие  ошибки c вашим урл (ключом), пример
вызываем http://ip/zabbix/123test . такой страницы нет у заббикса поэтому в 
`/var/log/httpd/zabbix/error_log` у меня появится строка :

```
[date] [error] [client ip] File does not exist: /usr/share/zabbix/123test
```

настраивает айтим для парсинга логов на поиск вашей ошибки и вешаете на нее триггер.

Answer (score -1):

Была подобная задача - надо было отправлять сообщения из 1C

Описал на хабре довольно подробно, если что - https://habr.com/en/post/253799/
Принимает запросы вида

```
zabbix.domain.com/zabbix_sender/index.php?server=myhost&key=testitem&value=11,
```

Это решение как раз вида

> 2. PHP-скрипт со стороны Zabbix Server

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)